# Transform plain text as a css value with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I'm making a style guide and I have disabled css in pre markup that I'm trying to apply as valid css to example boxes above.

Easier to understand with markup (please don't mind the weird indentation, it's done on purpose to simplify rendering. Also "defaut" is the french word for "default") :

```
<div id="styleguide" class="field-style">

    <div class="colored">
    </div>
    <pre><code class="language-less">
@defaut: #000;
</code></pre>

    <div class="colored">
    </div>
    <pre><code class="language-less">
@defaut: #e55240;
</code></pre>

    <div class="colored">
    </div>
    <pre><code class="language-less">
@defaut: #fff;
</code></pre>

</div>
```

I tried several variations but it doesn't work. Here is my latest attempt. In here I'm trying to select via regex everything up to and including '#', and delete it. Then I get the numbers and put them in background style. You could say I should filter directly to only select numerical values via regex, but it didnt't work either and I don't know why

```
$('.field-style .colored').each(function() {
var $this = $(this);

$this.css(
    'background', '#' +
    $this
    .next('pre')
    .children('code')
    .text()
    .replace('/^(.*?\\#)|;/', '')
);
```

Comment: Did you see `default` is spelled incorrectly?

Comment: sorry, it's actually the french word for "default". so it's spelled correctly in this instance because that langage was intended. Maybe a translation would be appropriate then

Comment: Ah, that's fine then.

Comment: Why not take the text, trim it and split it on the `:` character, then you know [0] is the attribute (if it starts with @ you could easily know its a special one) and use [1] as the value? So... `$(this).css('background', $(this).next().children('code').text().split(':')[1].trim())` That method makes it easier to apply later as well, as you could use [0] as the attribute if thats defined or something...

Comment: @somethinghere thanks, but it doesn't work, jquery doesn't produce any background property. That should be because the semi colon is still here with that method, I should remove it and see

Comment: Soooo.... `$(this).css('background', $(this).next().children('code').text().split(':')[1].trim().replace(';',''))` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the colon to split the text and take the second value resulting from it, then removing the semicolon:

```
$(this).css(
    'background',
     $(this).next().text()
        .split(':')[1]
        .trim()
        .replace(';','')
);
```

Comment: can also drop the `children()` and still get same results

Comment: @charlietfl Thats true, I'll do that.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from ensuring that your target `div`s are either not empty or have some height, you need to:

either replace your prefix and trim the textContent to get rid of trailing spaces/breaks along with getting rid of the last `;`:

```
$this.next().find('code').text().replace('@defaut: ', '').trim().slice(0, -1)
```

or split on `:` and rest on the second element of the resulting array:

```
$this.next().find('code').text().split(':')[1].trim().slice(0, -1)
```

**Demo**:

```js
$('.colored').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this), 
        prop = $this.next().find('code').text().replace('@defaut: ', '').trim().slice(0, -1)
    ;
    $this.css({'background-color': prop });
});
```

```css
div.colored { height: 16px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="styleguide" class="field-style">

    <div class="colored">First</div>
    <pre><code class="language-less">
@defaut: #f00;
</code></pre>

    <div class="colored">Second</div>
    <pre><code class="language-less">
@defaut: #0f0;
</code></pre>

    <div class="colored">Third</div>
    <pre><code class="language-less">
@defaut: #00f;
</code></pre>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I did chose the second solution in the end. I shouldn't try to mess with regex next time and use js methods

Comment: @topleft It is worth getting to grips with Regex's though. Something like `(/(.+#)/` would have been fine. (`.replace(/(\n.+#)/, '').replace(';','');`). It's probably not the best choice for what you're trying to achieve though, and the accept answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

There's a two issues with your regular expression:

- There's a newline between the `code` tag and `@defaut` which will not be matched by the `.`. From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions:

  > (The decimal point) matches any single character except the newline character.

  Use `trim()` to get rid of leading and trailing space.
- The regular expression must not be enclosed in quotes, otherwise it will be treated as a regular string. Use `replace(/^(.*?\\#)|;/)` instead.

As a further note it might be better to get the color value by extracting it instead of deleting everything else around it:

```
$this
    .next('pre')
    .children('code')
    .text().match(/@defaut:\s*(#.+?);/)[1]
```

This regular expression will look for "@defaut:" potentially followed whitespace, then followed by a color value terminated by a semicolon and extract the color value. An added avantage is that this solution won't break as easily in case you have to add more data inside the `<code>` tag or change the formatting.